# Count certain elements in ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, count, element

I want to count certain elements in an ArrayList that contain a certain number.

```
int count = 0;
for (ArrayList a: ArrayLists) {
    if (a.getEverything == 50) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " people with with this age");
```

Problem with code is that it only counts once, I want it to count all elements with 50 in them. In my ArrayList there are 4 elements with 50 in them. So I want count to return 4. How can I do this?

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. are you sure you have more than one element that has 50 in it?

Comment: you can try printing a.getEverything inside for loop and check if it has 50 in it or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Suppose if you have `ArrayList<Integer>`, instead of looping the elements you can also make use of `Collections`to count the occurences:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arList.add(50);
arList.add(50);
arList.add(50);
arList.add(4);
arList.add(4);
System.out.println("No. of occurences of 50: "+Collections.frequency(arList, 50));
System.out.println("No. of occurences of 4: "+Collections.frequency(arList, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    count = Collections.frequency(a,50);
```